# Отсутствует перевод уведомления о получении привилегии

Tags: дефект, локализация, привилегии

Отсутствует перевод уведомления о получении привилегии на вкладке достижений и на странице участника.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> ###### На вкладке достижений

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> ###### В сводке на странице участника

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы. Будет на сайте в новых сборках.

Текущая rev 2022.2.9.41410