# Частичное отсутствие перевода в уведомлении о получении привилегии

Tags: дефект, локализация, привилегии

Частично отсутствует перевод в уведомлении о получении привилегии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: я знаю, что есть вопрос [Отсутствует перевод уведомления о получении привилегии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11897/), но там немного о другом.

Comment: Строка уже давно [есть в Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17114), поэтому надо писать на MSE. Хотя, возможно, это симметричное проявление [известного бага](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/339911).